# ford mondeo v6 st24

Tags: ford, ignition, headlight, mondeo

Just wondering if anyone can help as we have this Mondeo and all of a sudden all the ignition went and have no power at all.

Any suggestions as to what it might be? All the fuses are fine and still power is going to the interior lights and we still can lock the car.

Comment: Is it only the things that usually need the ignition switched on that are not working?  Do the hazard lights / horn / parking lights work?  If so, I would take a 1st guess at the ignition switch being faulty.

Comment: On starting is the engine cranking?

Comment: Did you buy the car used? if so, there might be a GPS tracker installed with a starter immobilizer. typically, they're under the dashboard near or even spliced into the OBD wiring.

Comment: Can you explain 'no power at all'?  You indicate you have interior lights though.  Where do you have no power?  Does the radio turn on?  Does the engine turn over?